# Android setImageDrawable set ImageView in default position?

Tags: android, imageview

Is it true? 
More than that `s.layout(x1, y1, x2, y2);` dont work after setImageDrawable. 
I just want move and rotate Image? Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize you can use the setLayoutParams in your ImageView.

Translate should be in your layout, if you want update it while running you should implement it onDraw in a View.

Rotate can be done in the Canvas at onDraw too.